# Show current loop counter every 2 seconds using Ajax in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webforms

I need to run a loop (a loop through records & take some action) on a button click event, I want to show current loop counter `i`  using UpdatePanel. it is not working for me I searched through net but count not find a similar example. It show the `lblCounter` loop counter after completing the loop, while I need to show the `lblCounter` for every counter.

What is the best way to do even if I have to delay statement as show in the code.

Code below is just an example. I would appreciate if some can help me with this example. I actually want to loop through each record in the table & send email to all user. No of user will not exceed more than 200 0r 300.

While it is sending email I was to update client screen with the number of email that have done out, this is the basic thing that I want to achieve using update panel.

Markup:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnLoop" runat="server" Text="Start"  onclick="btnLoop_Click"  /><br />

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPanelNewsletterProgress" runat="server"
    UpdateMode="Conditional" >
    <ContentTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="lblCounter" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label><br />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code:

```
protected void btnLoop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        // take some action like send email to user XXX
        lblCounter.Text = "Counter " + i.ToString() + " of 100";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @KnowledgeSeeker, take a look at my answer, it works, tell me if I haven't got your purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPanelNewsletterProgress" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" >
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="lblCounter" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label><br />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel> 

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Timer1.Enabled = true;
}

protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i;
    int.TryParse(ViewState["i"] != null ? ViewState["i"].ToString() : "0", out i);
    if(i == 100)
        Timer1.Enabled = false;
    lblCounter.Text = "Counter " + i.ToString() + " of 100";
    ViewState["i"] = ++i;
}
```

I use ViewState technique in order to not lose the counter.
it works, let me know if you meant something different.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker you don't need the loop anymore, I showed you how to work with i 100 times, you can do the same thing you want to do in loop in my code, before ++ing i do your code, you have the counter, if you want for example a db row it's ok you have i you can fetch it.

Comment: Cool, i will try this but i am not sure if this is a professional approach. It should work & looks fine small number of records. BUt i feel this is a dangerous approach if you want to send Newsletter with this .. what do you say?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is professional, what I know is that it works fine :) I hope it helps. Why dangerous? you have a counter that works, if you use a loop it's the same story, there is a counter, what aspect of danger do you mean? Give me an example.

Comment: @ Mahdi, Risk involved in your approach [Checkout](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx)

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker I'll be happy to see your professional solution as soon as you found one, and I hope my solution helps you till then :) be careful with my dangerous code meanwhile

Comment: @ Mehdi, No offense i appreciate you code it is a good solution & works I have given my Up Vote for it. It is just something which  i dont want to use may be due the lack of knowledge i have. Appreciate your help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17685/discussion-between-knowledgeseeker-and-mahdi-tahsildari)

Answer (score 0):

You can user Asp Timer control to update your progress.

```
        <!-- The timer which used to update the progress. -->
        <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="100" Enabled="false" ontick="Timer1_Tick"></asp:Timer>

       <!-- The Label which used to display the progress and the result -->
         <asp:Label ID="lblCounter" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label><br />            </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Or you can use background worker class for updating progress in seperate thread.

Or you can also use Update progress control for progress updates as below:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
        <asp:UpdateProgress runat="server" id="PageUpdateProgress">
            <ProgressTemplate>
                Loading...
            </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="Panel">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Button runat="server" id="UpdateButton" onclick="UpdateButton_Click" text="Update" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
```

Comment: How can i do it from the loop, I mean invoke timer as i need to update loop every X seconds.. & variable `i` itself is part of loop. I am not sure about this i will give it a try.. .

Comment: I am using Using `UpdateProgress` but i want to replace it with the Counter to show progress.

Comment: You can do it from loop in Timer1_Tick which is on ontick event...<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="100" Enabled="false" ontick="Timer1_Tick"></asp:Timer>

Comment: by using update progress, you should drop your counter label in update progress.  <asp:UpdateProgress runat="server" id="PageUpdateProgress"> 
            <ProgressTemplate> 
                <!-- The Label which used to display the progress and the result --> 
         <asp:Label ID="lblCounter" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label><br /></ProgressTemplate> 
        </asp:UpdateProgress>

Comment: DO you mean i should define loop inside Timer1_Tick event, if so then my loop loop will execute every time. May be i dint get your point